# Android Custom Scrollbar Icon

Tags: android

I would like to know the exact steps to set the icon that appears when rapidly scrolling on a list view.  This appears as a silver icon with three lines through it.  Not certain what the name of this is. I think it might be called the thumb.  Please post a detailed response that shows the exact steps to replace this with my own image.  Also where might I find in the sdk the little silver icon so I can size mine correctly or indicate the dimensions of it.

Answer (score 0):

Create your style and apply to your scrollview

```
style name="code_droid_style">  
    <item name="android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack">true</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarStyle">outsideOverlay</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:fadeScrollbars">false</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/code_droid_thumb</item>
</style>
```

I think the default exists here: `..\platforms\android-N\data\resscrollbar_handle_accelerated_anim2.9` , search this type and you should find it